# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Connect after some time (File not found error)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maintenance

I've a root server with `Window Server 2008 R2` where `MS SQL Server 2012` is installed. Get a error while connecting.

**Management Studio Error Message**
File not found

This error only occur directly after start. Then i wait 2 Minutes. Everything is working. Leave the server some time and this problem occurs again.

I've installed before a instance of `.SQLEXPRESS`. I got an error while installing. The service is still installed for some reason. After this i've done a install of the default instance `MSSQL`. Right now i try to connect to directly to `MSSQL` and forget about `.SQLEXPRESS`.

Maybe the solution is to remove everything in relation to sql server and re-install, but the file not found exception seems like I've some trouble because it's a virtual server ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're losing the path to the storage location where SQL binaries are located.  It's hard to be sure, though, without knowing more about your environment (which hypervisor, what kind of storage are you using, etc).  When you get the error also try to browse to the file location to see if you are able to view the files.  If your host is connected to a SAN have your SAN admin check for errors related to the LUNs.

You could reinstall.  If you have nothing running on your instances yet it wouldn't hurt.  Your default instance installation should be fine; it should have everything it needs since you installed after the Express instance.